# AIR: How do I programmatically close a specific window

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am using a HTMLloader class in my application and would like to close the window programmatically when certain events occur. Is there a way to this?

```
private var hLoader:HTMLLoader;
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(50,50, 780, 500);
hLoader = HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true,null,true,rect);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nw:NativeWindow = hLoader.stage.nativeWindow;
```

That's how to get a reference to the window to which the hLoader belongs. Now, we can do things like listen for a mouseEvent and close the window. Example:

```
someButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   if(hLoader != null){
       var nw:NativeWindow = hLoader.stage.nativeWindow;
       nw.close();
   }
}
```