# How do I close a HTMLLoader window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am launching an HTMLLoader window from my flex application but I can't for the life of me work out how to close it! I am sure I need to get hold of the NativeWindow object but I just can't figure out how to get it!

Hopefully a nice easy question for someone!

I am using Flex 4.10.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was already answered here:

[AIR: How do I programmatically close a specific window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603976/air-how-do-i-programmatically-close-a-specific-window)

```
   var nw:NativeWindow = hLoader.stage.nativeWindow;
   nw.close();
```